# Should I deploy ngen native image Entity Framework 6 assemblies with my web application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ngen

One of the performance recommendations for Entity Framework 6 is to ngen the assemblies to avoid them being JIT'd on application startup.

However, there is very little information about whether this should be done on the server where the application is running, or whether I should just deploy the generated EntityFramework.ni.dll files from my dev machine into my web application bin folder.

What is the recommended practise for this?

Comment: As far as I know ngen does not support cross compilation. Therefore if you are sure that your local machine and the server have the same operating system and cpu architecture, then indeed you can do this locally and deploy it only. It is safer to do this on the server side though.

Comment: @freakish Ok that's an interesting thought. Though my understanding was that as long as it's both 32 or 64 bit for a specific .net framework then all is good. I will need to look into that a bit more.

Comment: Btw, have you considered using [native aot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot) instead? I've heard it works very well, at least with .Net8.

Comment: Ngen improves warm startup perf, not a concern for web apps.  The supported scenario is to use the WiX toolkit to create an installer that schedules Ngen to be run on the target machine.  Not something you'd ever do for a web app.  Ngen is no longer relevant for .NET5+ targets.  Three reasons to not bother, there may be more.

Comment: @Hans. I'm still targeting .NET 4.8, and additionally the CPU performance on a cold startup on the web app is high, so still a consideration in my context. But yes, I understand the benefit is going to be tiny.